# Task manager "Last BIOS Time"

Tags: windows-10, task-manager

I under stand what it does and how it works, (measures how long it takes from pressing the power button to indicating the computer is loading) but it seems to be inaccurate or something because my craptop that takes a solid 2 minutes to boot got 3.6 seconds (not unbelievable) but my PC with an SSD took 16.5 seconds. Another user said their SSD got 1.9 seconds. Where is the mistake? How do I fix it?

[image: BIOS time on laptop]

Comment: ignore this value and trace your possible slow boot with xbootmgr/WPRUI

Comment: Most laptops are usually fast (2 seconds or so) while most desktops slower (from 7 to over 15 seconds).

Comment: The value means "time from power on to booting (starting loading the OS)"

Answer (score 0):

The **Last BIOS Time** is the time your computer takes to turn on before Windows (POST).This includes things like turning on the screen , fan , HDD. So this won't be your Windows boot time